Issues with Netlify form submissions in my next.js 14 project
I’m having trouble getting Netlify's form submission to work with my Next.js 14 project. I've followed Netlify's recommendations, activated form submissions within Netlify, and set up a hidden form in the public folder. Here’s what I have so far:
__forms.html in the public folder:
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form name="contact" data-netlify="true" hidden>
      <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact" />
      <input name="name" type="text" />
      <input name="email" type="email" />
      <input name="company" type="text" />
      <input name="phone" type="tel" />
      <input name="message" type="text" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

ContactForm component:
import { useState } from 'react';

function ContactForm() {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const handleFormSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      setStatus('pending');
      setError(null);
      const form = event.target;
      const formData = new FormData(form);
      const res = await fetch('/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: new URLSearchParams(formData).toString(),
      });
      if (res.ok) {
        setStatus('ok');
        form.reset(); // Clear the form inputs
      } else {
        throw new Error(`Error: ${res.status} ${res.statusText}`);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setStatus('error');
      setError(e.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form
      name="contact"
      method="POST"
      data-netlify="true"
      onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
    >
      <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact" />
      <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Name" />
      <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Email" />
      <input type="text" name="company" required placeholder="Company" />
      <input type="tel" name="phone" required placeholder="Phone" />
      <input type="text" name="message" required placeholder="Message" />
      <button type="submit" disabled={status === 'pending' || status === 'ok'}>
        {status === 'ok' ? 'Message sent' : status === 'pending' ? 'Sending...' : 'Send message'}
      </button>
      {status === 'error' && <div>Error: {error}</div>}
    </form>
  );
}

export default ContactForm;

Despite this setup, form submissions are not being recorded in Netlify. I’ve ensured that form submissions are enabled in Netlify. What might I be missing or doing wrong?
I am using Next.js 14.0.4.
The form appears correctly on the site but submissions don't show up in Netlify's form dashboard. Netlify also detects the form (probably the html form within my public folder), but not any submissions.
I have tried reading Netlify's article: Next.js on Netlify (https://docs.netlify.com/frameworks/next-js/overview/) and their starter templates, specifically the __forms.html (https://github.com/netlify-templates/next-platform-starter/blob/main/public/__forms.html) file and the feedback-form.jsx (https://github.com/netlify-templates/next-platform-starter/blob/main/components/feedback-form.jsx) file.
I expected the form submissions to appear in Netlify's form dashboard. However, despite the setup, the submissions are not being recorded. The form appears correctly on the site, but the submissions are not visible in Netlify.

<form name="contact" data-netlify="true" method="post" hidden>

Add method="post" in the __forms.html that solved it for me after trying for two days.
